when i install vscode in window 10 it keep asking me and prompting

I tried to run it as root or administrator from power shell but it does not work. I also tried to disable the control access in Windows Defender but it does not work for me. For more I installed this operating system before a while it was working in my previous Windows but after I reinstalled Windows it behaves in odd way. I installed the operation system from the offical Windows on Microsoft site.
